# C++ static (string) member initialization logic

Tags: c++, static, constexpr

Why do I get compiler error in the 2nd and 3rd lines (see below) but not the first one?

```
struct X {
  static constexpr const char* f1 = "f1"; // ok
  static const char* f2 = "f2";          // error
  static const std::string f3 = "f3";  // error

};
```

Answer (score 0):

`constexpr` required to be initialized or constructed immediately, and other static members in a translation unit within the same namespace.

```
const std::string X::f3 = "f3";
```

Comment: An *ODR-used* thing that I will never understand I think.